# Remote REST request to check login status

Tags: login, rest-api, remote

There are 2 wp installations, A and B.

Is it possible to do a remote rest request from site A to find out if an user is logged into site B? If yes, how?

With this information adjustments would be made on site A according to whether user is logged into site B or not.

Comment: Probably related https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/295471/nonce-retrieved-from-the-rest-api-is-invalid-and-different-from-nonce-generated/295547